# Xcode8: Swift compile errors when my connected iPhone is the destination

Tags: swift, xcode

When i run my program with the simulator it builds and runs with no errors. However when i change the destination to my connected iPhone, a whole bunch of swift compile errors are displayed:

1. Attempting to use the forward class 'UIViewController' as superclass of 'UIActivityViewController'
2. Attempting to use the forward class 'UIViewController' as superclass of 'UIAlertController'

a bunch of those, and then

3. Cannot define category for undefined class 'UIViewController' UINavigationController.h
   and a bunch of these as well ...

I'm very new to Xcode and can't figure these errors out ...

Comment: Xcode version? Phone OS version please?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your compiling towards different iOS versions on the device and the simulator. This may cause the compiler compiling towards different Swift versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it by cleaning the derived data.

Delete your DerivedData folder in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

But would also Clean the project and Reset Content and Settings.